# Changing solution to a fraction rather than integer multiples

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel spreadsheet. I have column C which has price values. In column D, I have the date. In column E, I want to return the first time the current price reaches is doubled.

So for example, if C1 is $1 and the first time column C gets to $2 is C27, then  I would want to return the date of E27 to E1. Note that the range lookup has to change. For instance, for C2, we don't want to look at C1 to see if the price is doubled. Basically, we cannot go back in time. The solution to this is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($C2:$C$10000)/($C2*2<=$C2:$C$10000),1)),"Does not Double")
```

But what if I want to find the first time the current value is cut in half? I tried changing the *2 to *0.5 but it does not work. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Doesn't `($C2*0.5>=$C2:$C$10000)` solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe `=IFERROR(INDEX(E2:E$10000,MATCH(C2*2,C2:C$10000,0)),"")`?

Comment: @Jeeped no this does not fix it

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad huh? I already have 2x working, see my post. When I change it to 0.5, it does not work